# How to count the maximum number of simultaneously present entities by column value?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that shows the arrival and departure (`type`), the time (`time`) of the vehicles (`vehicle_id`) on a network of multiple roads (`links`).

My goal is to see how many vehicles are maximum at the same time present on a link to determine the minimum number of parking lots per link.

For clarification; `type=="vehicle enters traffic"` means the car leaves the parking lot. `type=="vehicle leaves traffic"` means it enters the parking lot.

I dont know how to write the code, I assume with `dplyr` it could be done, but my approach would be like this:

1. group by link
2. sort the subset with increasing time (chronological order of events)
3. If `type=="vehicle enters traffic"`, which means the vehicle was there before, I already know one parking lot is present. So for the first seconds, i know how many stayed overnight (time 0 is midnight).
4. Every time a  `type=="vehicle leaves traffic"` on the link without  `type=="vehicle enters traffic"`, the maximum number of parking lot increases.

I hope this is more or less clear.

In the end I desire a simple df with a column for the link number and a column with the number of maximum present vehicles.

I very much appreciate your help!

Data to try:

```
structure(list(time = c(25466, 29180, 29181, 39304, 40237, 40818, 
42895, 52773, 53829, 59208, 59239, 68389, 24607, 25218, 29947, 
37637, 42623, 43930, 43965, 46223, 51518, 57738, 63527, 65623, 
27505, 28177, 28499, 60605, 63184, 63252, 20959, 26376, 47805, 
49549, 50644, 61197, 78557, 79249, 29169, 31411, 34626, 36747, 
38807, 44618, 58068, 58800, 65431, 69056, 46559, 69920, 20445, 
23764, 24017, 24281, 25301, 27161, 27289, 28783, 28910, 29241, 
29393, 29489, 29549, 29909, 30731, 31092, 31356, 31786, 32829, 
33966, 34094, 34545, 34888, 35775, 35950, 38409, 38636, 39259, 
39527, 40256, 40385, 40564, 40691, 40774, 42271, 42461, 43103, 
43223, 44476, 44903, 44904, 45774, 45834, 45915, 46194, 46626, 
47215, 48784, 50266, 50361, 50763, 52685, 52793, 54688, 55105, 
56310, 57885, 58046, 58118, 59223, 60460, 60597, 60676, 61307, 
61446, 62165, 62347, 62591, 63325, 64155, 65555, 65808, 66038, 
66723, 66729, 66789, 66790, 67502, 67989, 68322, 69318, 69639, 
70450, 70634, 71741, 72121, 72292, 73236, 73775, 74280, 80298, 
80458, 80976, 81035, 84189, 84302, 23333, 32549, 34024, 57385, 
26137, 26163, 27473, 28303, 29206, 31052, 34019, 36023, 36392, 
40717, 43182, 44063, 44064, 44709, 44770, 46863, 48318, 48493, 
51718, 52221, 52599, 52923, 53443, 54494, 55053, 58381, 62610, 
63050, 63050, 63417, 63488, 64067, 65090, 65090, 65185, 66571, 
67715, 68247, 68921, 68955, 70123, 70263, 71359, 77855, 23423, 
23770, 29044, 29053, 32320, 32735, 66884, 67902, 68763, 69206, 
34426, 64393, 32354, 64161, 67761, 25657, 26173, 33923, 35452, 
36914, 38663, 43256, 49564, 50619, 55540, 56403, 73247, 73873, 
77960, 41750, 44879, 47284, 48132, 49418, 50628, 57823, 57824, 
62292, 62293, 66103, 78862, 35841, 42188, 42719, 43543, 23581, 
27573, 45463, 48723, 49182, 52246, 53664, 60310, 61756, 63941, 
64363, 68181, 68182, 80056, 26885, 44885, 45701, 49570, 50407, 
52044, 53566, 55712, 56463, 59266, 63829, 65907, 44795, 52245, 
21619, 21897, 24808, 27283, 28827, 29304, 30437, 31426, 31673, 
32971, 33595, 33962, 39556, 39624, 40347, 41473, 42396, 43000, 
43377, 46795, 47635, 53664, 57927, 57942, 58559, 59187, 59932, 
60068, 61162, 61730, 65144, 65281, 67215), type = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("vehicle enters traffic", 
"vehicle leaves traffic"), class = "factor"), vehicle_id = c(1267068L, 
810534L, 810534L, 532654L, 1111105L, 1111105L, 532654L, 46491L, 
46491L, 4205L, 4205L, 1267068L, 1454119L, 1412246L, 1533113L, 
1430553L, 1430553L, 1430553L, 1533113L, 1430553L, 492533L, 492533L, 
1454119L, 1412246L, 1290940L, 628509L, 558745L, 628509L, 558745L, 
1290940L, 403850L, 774916L, 1397256L, 403850L, 3874L, 774916L, 
1397256L, 3874L, 1043798L, 1043798L, 1221124L, 1881121L, 1881121L, 
1221124L, 12799L, 12799L, 2066556L, 2066556L, 488147L, 488147L, 
1925302L, 2821L, 1919641L, 2147547L, 1785664L, 1869032L, 1812540L, 
1531804L, 1814856L, 1531804L, 2149105L, 1747951L, 1908352L, 1854886L, 
1888344L, 1926462L, 1925659L, 1887358L, 1926462L, 1863281L, 1094609L, 
1888344L, 1925659L, 2148165L, 1863281L, 2148165L, 1814856L, 1885007L, 
1094609L, 1887358L, 1925302L, 1925659L, 1908352L, 1919641L, 1885007L, 
1898426L, 2095866L, 1812540L, 2149105L, 1799420L, 1799420L, 1898426L, 
2095866L, 1905635L, 1859644L, 1187619L, 1794294L, 1908352L, 1187619L, 
2149105L, 1901830L, 1859644L, 1885718L, 1925659L, 4806833L, 1901830L, 
1794294L, 4806833L, 2821L, 1905635L, 1785664L, 1887788L, 2149105L, 
1885718L, 1912658L, 1869032L, 2147547L, 1908352L, 1670344L, 2064554L, 
1902958L, 1888247L, 1888247L, 1898186L, 1840443L, 1378838L, 1378838L, 
1747951L, 1887788L, 5259385L, 2064554L, 42794L, 1912658L, 1887316L, 
1860654L, 1902958L, 1854886L, 5259385L, 1887316L, 1670344L, 42794L, 
1921295L, 1921295L, 1860654L, 1840443L, 1898186L, 80518L, 1131784L, 
1131784L, 80518L, 29916L, 29916L, 519878L, 525457L, 523658L, 
523658L, 526214L, 29916L, 526214L, 479492L, 1856482L, 568524L, 
568524L, 693877L, 479492L, 29916L, 1856482L, 693877L, 520491L, 
520491L, 513349L, 29916L, 513349L, 532803L, 530834L, 526134L, 
398460L, 519877L, 519877L, 533986L, 476491L, 525457L, 519877L, 
519877L, 398460L, 530834L, 519878L, 532803L, 476491L, 537161L, 
533986L, 29916L, 526134L, 537161L, 273572L, 273572L, 861460L, 
861460L, 216294L, 216294L, 1535243L, 230658L, 230658L, 1535243L, 
1428056L, 1428056L, 1140384L, 46083L, 1140384L, 1257243L, 1455977L, 
22182L, 22182L, 1461901L, 1461901L, 1257243L, 1257242L, 1257242L, 
1196859L, 1196859L, 1455977L, 1455977L, 1455977L, 1903824L, 1903824L, 
566328L, 566328L, 1199966L, 1199966L, 1536111L, 1536111L, 2006467L, 
2006467L, 6035493L, 6035493L, 5858613L, 5858613L, 1160146L, 1160146L, 
1747160L, 1811944L, 1811944L, 4682113L, 1811944L, 1058129L, 1058129L, 
4682113L, 1792899L, 1747160L, 1811944L, 1747496L, 1747496L, 1792899L, 
1960095L, 1960095L, 1960095L, 311665L, 1794698L, 1794698L, 311665L, 
1720159L, 1720159L, 1960095L, 1886261L, 1886261L, 1418046L, 1418046L, 
1333818L, 1269837L, 1375263L, 26265L, 1318735L, 1318735L, 1858598L, 
1923074L, 13778L, 1162037L, 1043247L, 1173884L, 1883621L, 13778L, 
11914L, 1375263L, 1209156L, 1883621L, 1858598L, 1923074L, 1360458L, 
1333820L, 26265L, 1333818L, 1162037L, 11914L, 1333820L, 1043247L, 
1269837L, 14229L, 1173884L, 1882652L, 1360458L), link = c(90L, 
90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 389L, 
389L, 389L, 389L, 389L, 389L, 389L, 389L, 389L, 389L, 389L, 389L, 
451L, 451L, 451L, 451L, 451L, 451L, 480L, 480L, 480L, 480L, 480L, 
480L, 480L, 480L, 578L, 578L, 578L, 578L, 578L, 578L, 578L, 578L, 
578L, 578L, 662L, 662L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 
723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 
723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 
723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 
723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 
723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 
723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 
723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 
723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 723L, 
723L, 774L, 774L, 774L, 774L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 
859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 
859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 
859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 
859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 859L, 927L, 927L, 927L, 927L, 927L, 927L, 
927L, 927L, 927L, 927L, 987L, 987L, 988L, 988L, 988L, 1277L, 
1277L, 1277L, 1277L, 1277L, 1277L, 1277L, 1277L, 1277L, 1277L, 
1277L, 1277L, 1277L, 1277L, 1476L, 1476L, 1476L, 1476L, 1476L, 
1476L, 1476L, 1476L, 1476L, 1476L, 1476L, 1476L, 1478L, 1478L, 
1478L, 1478L, 1706L, 1706L, 1706L, 1706L, 1706L, 1706L, 1706L, 
1706L, 1706L, 1706L, 1706L, 1706L, 1706L, 1706L, 1713L, 1713L, 
1713L, 1713L, 1713L, 1713L, 1713L, 1713L, 1713L, 1713L, 1713L, 
1713L, 2472L, 2472L, 2482L, 2482L, 2482L, 2482L, 2482L, 2482L, 
2482L, 2482L, 2482L, 2482L, 2482L, 2482L, 2482L, 2482L, 2482L, 
2482L, 2482L, 2482L, 2482L, 2482L, 2482L, 2482L, 2482L, 2482L, 
2482L, 2482L, 2482L, 2482L, 2482L, 2482L, 2482L, 2482L, 2482L
)), row.names = c(23238L, 42556L, 42563L, 81015L, 84161L, 86265L, 
95521L, 137820L, 141613L, 163931L, 164087L, 216307L, 18965L, 
21973L, 46226L, 75475L, 94175L, 100651L, 100815L, 111088L, 133134L, 
156818L, 189497L, 202055L, 33842L, 37370L, 39040L, 171595L, 187438L, 
187844L, 5468L, 27947L, 117806L, 125360L, 129715L, 175097L, 241042L, 
241962L, 42500L, 52783L, 65128L, 72377L, 79465L, 103961L, 158322L, 
161850L, 200947L, 219162L, 112417L, 222619L, 4375L, 15072L, 16200L, 
17395L, 22407L, 32033L, 32706L, 40478L, 41133L, 42874L, 43583L, 
44072L, 44337L, 46039L, 49745L, 51373L, 52526L, 54342L, 58676L, 
62850L, 63317L, 64867L, 66035L, 69170L, 69761L, 78130L, 78885L, 
80865L, 81774L, 84223L, 84679L, 85315L, 85792L, 86117L, 92427L, 
93399L, 96540L, 97130L, 103259L, 105331L, 105336L, 109169L, 109451L, 
109813L, 110965L, 112683L, 115212L, 122086L, 128227L, 128591L, 
130215L, 137505L, 137888L, 144612L, 146164L, 150731L, 157472L, 
158213L, 158602L, 164005L, 170740L, 171536L, 172007L, 175750L, 
176593L, 181026L, 182216L, 183756L, 188258L, 193346L, 201644L, 
203116L, 204405L, 208077L, 208109L, 208419L, 208425L, 211997L, 
214395L, 215965L, 220248L, 221537L, 224574L, 225219L, 228716L, 
229792L, 230292L, 232476L, 233674L, 234734L, 243350L, 243574L, 
244226L, 244294L, 247553L, 247644L, 13209L, 57522L, 63071L, 155252L, 
26694L, 26839L, 33677L, 38038L, 42692L, 51204L, 63048L, 69987L, 
71140L, 85891L, 96919L, 101289L, 101294L, 104414L, 104689L, 113653L, 
120044L, 120801L, 133881L, 135808L, 137165L, 138335L, 140184L, 
143967L, 145971L, 159850L, 183879L, 186653L, 186654L, 188805L, 
189240L, 192828L, 198961L, 198962L, 199507L, 207302L, 213037L, 
215619L, 218593L, 218735L, 223408L, 223918L, 227558L, 240109L, 
13584L, 15098L, 41858L, 41911L, 56556L, 58294L, 208921L, 213974L, 
217961L, 219770L, 64477L, 194837L, 56728L, 193388L, 213272L, 
24235L, 26897L, 62706L, 68026L, 72951L, 78988L, 97296L, 125423L, 
129612L, 147786L, 151099L, 232501L, 233905L, 240245L, 89980L, 
105210L, 115503L, 119239L, 124778L, 129647L, 157204L, 157210L, 
181836L, 181845L, 204756L, 241443L, 69403L, 92041L, 94643L, 98793L, 
14292L, 34219L, 107838L, 121810L, 123716L, 135908L, 141019L, 
169910L, 178466L, 192072L, 194657L, 215315L, 215320L, 243029L, 
30590L, 105241L, 108824L, 125451L, 128782L, 135129L, 140632L, 
148441L, 151345L, 164243L, 191385L, 203666L, 104817L, 135901L, 
7216L, 8092L, 19915L, 32672L, 40686L, 43160L, 48417L, 52850L, 
53867L, 59198L, 61526L, 62837L, 81879L, 82110L, 84554L, 88640L, 
93066L, 96036L, 97944L, 113344L, 117026L, 141017L, 157645L, 157714L, 
160682L, 163809L, 167774L, 168536L, 174921L, 178302L, 199276L, 
200098L, 210574L), class = "data.frame")
```

Desired result based on the first 3 links:

```
link    max_vehicles
90      2
389     2
451     3
...
```

Comment: It would be easier If you share your expected output based on the example you shared

Comment: Its quite a tricky thing to do by hand, one easily discounts. I've added it for the first 3 links now:)

Comment: @Yves For `id` 90 I only get 1 count. Could you explain how you achieves 2 in `max_vehicles`?

Comment: @Duck sure; at time ```39304```, vehicle ```532654``` leaves traffic and at ```40237``` vehicle ```1111105``` leaves traffic as well. I.e. both of them park there at the same time. That is the only time the occupancy is 2, besides this it always drops to 1 or 0. This is the chronological occupancy: 1-0-1-0-1-2-1-0-1-0-1

Answer (score 1):

This looks a bit cumbersome but it does what you need. It basically groups by link and type **BUT** in a sense where everytime the type changes, it is a new group (hence the `rleid()` from `data.table` - We can avoid loading an extra package and implement it ourselves with a combination of `cumsum` and `diff`, or use the base R `rle` with some modifications, but I went with the fast option). We then sort on `time`, filter out the rows where cars are leaving the parking lots and count the number of rows in each group. We  then re-group by `link` in order to remove the grouping of `rleid()` and filter to get the one with the maximum value (`slice(which.max())`). Finally we remove the extra column created for the `rleid()` grouping.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 group_by(link, grp = data.table::rleid(type)) %>% 
 arrange(time) %>% 
 filter(type == 'vehicle leaves traffic') %>% 
 count() %>% 
 group_by(link) %>% 
 slice(which.max(n)) %>% 
 select(-grp)

# A tibble: 19 x 2
# Groups:   link [19]
#    link     n
#   <int> <int>
# 1    90     2
# 2   389     2
# 3   451     3
# 4   480     3
# 5   578     2
# 6   662     1
# 7   723     9
# 8   774     2
# 9   859     4
#10   927     2
#11   987     1
#12   988     1
#13  1277     2
#14  1476     2
#15  1478     1
#16  1706     3
#17  1713     3
#18  2472     1
#19  2482     7
```

Comment: Wow that does seem to work for you! I somehow run into a problem: Error in which.max(n) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'. do you know what might cause this?

Comment: Hmmm...did you call a function instead of a variable? Does it work for you on the example you shared? Maybe investigate your dataset up to the `count()` to see what is going on

Comment: I take it back. Restarted a clean R session. no idea what the issue was :) thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry to ask later, only now I've realized an issue with this code. So basically you are counting the longest string of  ```type == 'vehicle leaves traffic'```, checking how many cars park before one car exits, right?  However, it can be that one ```type == 'vehicle enters traffic'``` is followed by two ```type == 'vehicle leaves traffic'```, so the total number is actual even one more (at least).  I belive this solution does not take this into consideration, am I right? I've just applied it to my data and the results do not make much sense when comparing scenarios with different park policy.